# How to use a native code in corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

> How to use a native code in corona sdk?

hi am  stuck in how to use native code of android in corona.any one explain how to attach native code step by step...

---

thank u

Answer (score 2):

I don't know step by step because I don't have Corona Enterprise.

And to do that you need Corona Enterprise...

But Corona Enterprise works basically as a sort of native API too that you link against your native app, and to use native things inside Corona Enterprise you would code the native code version of it, make a lua binding and call from inside Corona.

Comment: FYI: there's documentation on the native API's here: http://docs.coronalabs.com/native/index.html

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.coronalabs.com/native/index.html, you need to buy the corona enterprise edition for using native Api coding : https://coronalabs.com/pricing/